# Remove/hide contacts of one account when multiple Google accounts are added to Phone

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I have added two Google accounts to my phone running Android 12. Contacts of both accounts are now being shown on the device.

Is there a way I can remove/hide the contacts of one account? Note that I do not wish to remove the account just want to remove/hide the contacts for this device.

Thanks

Comment: I encouraged users of the Google Contacts help to submit their feedback in the app and tell the Google developers that they need this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once they are synced, you need to remove them yourself.

**To Stop them syncing**

- Go to Settings
- Account sand Backup (or Accounts and Sync)
- Select Manage Accounts (or accounts are displayed anyway)
- Select Account (From the ones with the Google Icon) (**Image-1**)
- Select Sync Account (**Image-2**)
- Turn off Contacts switch (**Image-3**)

**To remove the accounts**

- You can do it manually
- Or you can use a third party app such as `Contacts Optimizer` to help you
- I also find `MyPhoneExplorer` very handy.  You can copy the contacts to your OPC and manage them there.

**Image-1**

[image]

**Image-2**

[image]

**Image-3**

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the Google accounts need to be removed? Isn't there a way to hide the contacts without removing the Google account altogether?

Comment: You need to remove the account from the phone, not delete it from Google.

Comment: The question clearly states that he needs a solution that does *not* delete Google accounts from the phone. So this answer is not a solution to the question. It does not hide contacts for a particular Google account.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the contacts you see in the Google Contacts app to only display the contacts that are stored in a particular Google account's cloud storage. This is the best you can do, there isn't an easy way to permanently hide contacts from a Google account, you can only enable a filter. This has been tested on stock Android 14.

1. Open the Contacts app ([the one made by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts&hl=en_US&gl=US))
2. In the top right hand corner of the screen, click on the profile picture of your Google account. A list of Google accounts should be displayed now, alongside the menu options "Add another account", "Manage account on this device", and so forth.
3. Tap on the Google account that you want to focus on. The dialog should close and you should return to the main screen of the app.
4. Now tap on the hamburger menu icon in the top left corner of the screen. A sidebar should appear, with "All accounts", the name of the selected Google account, and then a list of labels.
5. Tap on the name of the Google account to filter contacts to just those stored on that Google account's cloud storage.

You can enable or disable Contacts sync for particular Google account, but that isn't enough to hide those contacts from the Contacts app.